# NDatabase List<T> into IBindingList

Tags: c#, oop, data-binding, ndatabase

I am using [NDatabase](http://ndatabase.codeplex.com/) and I am having trouble trying to bind a `IEnumerable<T>` which I am retrieving using a base Data Access Layer (`BaseDAL`).

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetMany<T>()
{
  using(var odb = OdbFactory("Example.db"))
  {
    return odb.AsQueryable<T>().ToList();
  }
}
```

`T` in my instance is `Employee`.

```
public interface IEmployee
{
  string Username { get; set; }
  List<UserConfiguration> ConfigurationList { get; set; }  
}
```

Essentially I need a `List<Employee>` which can be used to bind to a grid (currently I get that `the underlying datasource doesn't support editing`).

I know that I need to somehow implement `IBindingList`, however the implementation for this is huge! I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction? Or am I going to have to go along the lines of:

```
public class BindableList<T> : IObjectSet<T>, IBindingList {}
```

Thanks!

**NDatabase IObjectSet Structure**

```
public interface IObjectSet<TItem> : ICollection<TItem>, IEnumerable<TItem>, IEnumerable
{
  TItem GetFirst();
  bool HasNext();
  TItem Next();
  void Reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly me...

[`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms132679%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

The above takes a constructor of `IList` so I just need to change my `BaseDAL` method to this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetMany<T>()
{
  using(var odb = OdbFactory("Example.db"))
  {
    return new BindingList<T>(odb.AsQueryable<T>().ToList());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote could be improved in this way:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetMany<T>()
{
  using(var odb = OdbFactory("Example.db"))
  {
    return new BindingList<T>(odb.QueryAndExecute<T>().ToList());
  }
}
```

This code is not using all Linq to NDatabase things (wrappers) which you don't need in this case.